# CentOS Apache .htaccess: Options not allowed here (500 - Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos7

I am installing Apache in CentOS 7 and this is my **httpd.conf** - http://pastebin.com/raw/YeiLn7GN

This is my document root: **/home/host/public_html**

To test if `.htaccess` file works & if `mod_rewrite` is enabled, I've uploaded the sample `.htaccess` from a laravel project into `/home/host/public_html/.htaccess`, which has the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then uploaded the following php script: `/home/host/public_html/index.php`

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

When I visit `http://<my-server-ip>/index.php`, I get the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

I got found the following in `/var/log/httpd/apache_error_log` file:

> [Thu Dec 31 15:50:43.696465 2015] [core:alert] [pid 23807] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56536] /home/host/public_html/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

If I remove the following lines from the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

The script appears to load and no 500 error.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**.htaccess: Options not allowed here** error indicates that the htaccess file is not allowed to use the Options directive to change the settings.

To fix this error edit your apache config file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:-

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride Options
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Adding "Options" to the AllowOverride list, will permit the use of Options directive in htaccess file

Comment: Well it didn't help

Comment: At least I tryed to add this directive here /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
is this a correct location?